# Error in org-table-sum org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am just getting started with Emacs org-mode and I am already getting really confused about a simple column sum (org-table-sum). I start with

```
| date |   sum |
|------+-------|
|      |  16.2 |
|      |  6.16 |
|      |  6.16 |
|      |       |
```

When I hit `C-c +` (org-table-sum) below the second column I get the correct sum `28.52`. If I add another line to make it

```
| date |   sum |
|------+-------|
|      |  16.2 |
|      |  6.16 |
|      |  6.16 |
|      | 13.11 |
|      |       |
```

`C-c +` gives me `41.629999999999995`. ??? 
If I change the last line from `13.11`to `13.12`, `C-c +`will give me (the correct) `41.64`.
WTF?
Any explanation appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most decimal numbers cannot be represented exactly in binary floating point encoding (either single or double precision).

Test 13.11 [here](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), to see that after conversion to double precision, the nearest number represented is `13.109999656677246`.

This problem is not emacs related, but is a fundamental issue when working with floating point representation in a different base (binary rather than decimal).

Using calc's `vsum`, the result is OK:

```
| date |   sum |
|------+-------|
|      |  16.2 |
|      |  6.16 |
|      |  6.16 |
|      | 13.11 |
|------+-------|
|      | 41.63 |
#+TBLFM: @6$2=vsum(@I..@II)
```

This works because calc works with arbitrary precision and will not encode the numbers in a binary floating point format.